# rings of polynomials over $Z_p$ (part-2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An element of R is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $< r$ with coefficients from $Z_n$ (where $n$ is a composite number). We use the notation $a(x)$ to represent elements of $R$. Let $\phi :R \mapsto R$ 
Then I want to prove that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism if and only if 
$\phi(a(x))=a(x^n)$. Also all the addition and multiplication are addition mod n and multiplication mod n respectively.

---

What I've tried is this:

$(\Longleftarrow)$

Let $\phi(a(x))=a(x^n)$. Then,

$$a(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(x)^i $$ 
$$\phi(a(x))=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(x^n)^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: (\:\because n|ni\:) $$
$\phi(a(x) \cdot b(x))=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(x^n)^i) \cdot (\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j(x^n)^j)=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i) \cdot(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j) $
$ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: =\phi(a(x))\cdot \phi(b(x))$ 
Also, 
$\phi(a(x)+b(x))=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(x^n)^i) + (\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j(x^n)^j)=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i) + (\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j) $
$ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\ \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:= \phi(a(x)) + \phi(b(x))$ 
$ \therefore $ there exists a ring homomorphism

---

Is my proof from right side correct? I couldn't solve it from left side, can someone  help me there!

Comment: Is it a ring? I mean $f(x)=x$, and $g(x)=x^{r-1}$, then $f\cdot g$ doesn't have degree less than $r$?

Comment: $\{a(x)\in Z_n[x]\,:\,\deg(a(x))<r\}$ is never a ring, if $r>1$. Hence, $\phi$ cannot be a *ring* omomorphism.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i defined the operation in such a way that if you have $f(x)=x^k$ and $g(x)=x^m$ for some $k,m \in I $ Then $f(x) \cdot g(x) =x^{(k+m)modn}$

Comment: All the multiplication and addition are  addition mod n  and  multiplication mod n. So $R$ is a ring because it satisfy all the properties of the rings with the operation i defined.